# Advice needed for powering Multiple HX711 with Arduino Mega

Tags: arduino-mega, atmega2560

I have a project where I need to use multiple load cells (6-8), with individual HX711 for each load cell, which need to be powered simultaneously. I am not sure if I can power all the HX711 with 5V and GND pins of Arduino Mega or I need to use a separate 5V DC power supply and connect the VCC and GND of HX711 pins to it and connect the DT and SCK pins to the digital pins of the Mega. Will such an arrangement work?  Thanks for your time in advance. The link to the HX711 datasheet is [here](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/ForceFlex/hx711_english.pdf).

Comment: How much current does every HX711 need, including the load cell?

Comment: Hi Chrisl, as per the HX711 the digital supply current is 100 μA. I have edited my question to add the link to the HX711 datasheet. But the datasheet can also mention that - Digital power supply (DVDD) should be the same power supply as the MCU power supply. So I am unsure if the Mega can directly power 6-8 load cells.

Comment: The mega can theoretically power about 5000 HX711s.

Comment: And how much current does the load cell draw? You can easily draw 500mA from the 5V supply line on a Mega. (and the 100 μΑ load from a single HX711 is 1/5,000 of that amount.)